# Google Chart HtmlHelper for Asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

Are there any HtmlHelper Extensions for [Google Chart Api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)? (I like to use for some basic charts, e.g. Pie Chart, Bar Chart)

Soe Moe

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Google says that you insert a chart like this:

```
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?
    chs=250x100
    &amp;chd=t:60,40
    &amp;cht=p3
    &amp;chl=Hello|World" 
    alt="Sample chart" 
/>
```

So it should be easy enough to write an HtmlHelper like this (untested):

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class GoogleChartHelpers
    {
        public static string GoogleChart
            (string cht, string chd, string chs, string chl)
        {
            return "<img source='http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=" + cht 
                 + "&amp;chd=" + chd 
                 + "&amp;chs=" + chs 
                 + "&amp;chl=" + chl + "' />;
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
<%= Html.GoogleChart("P3","t:60,40","250x100","Hello|World") %>
```

which should insert this into your page:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

A C# wrapper for the Google Chart API.

http://code.google.com/p/googlechartsharp/

Usage examples

[http://code.google.com/p/googlechartsharp/wiki/UsageExamples](http://code.google.com/p/googlechartsharp/)

I'm sure you could create a HTMLHelper that incorporates this wrapper class to make it even easier.