# ASP.NET MVC HTML helper library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

There seems to be an abundance of jQuery plugins that you can grab and use quite easily.

Are there any HTML helper samples, examples or libraries that you can also download and use.

In particular I'm looking for free helpers. :)

I know helpers can be specific to applications, but it'd be great to see what others are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [FluentHtml Helpers](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FluentHtml&referringTitle=Documentation) in the [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) project.

Comment: Interesting, but apart from their fluent aspect, they don't seem to do anything new.

Comment: Good article on the rationale here: http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/mvcfluenthtml-fluent-html-interface-for-ms-mvc/

Comment: @griegs: I think you need to realise that apart from the projects mentioned here, MVC by design encourages developers to create their own helper libraries - that being one of the beauties of MVC (this may be why most devs are content to write their own). Also, because MVC is relatively new to the MS world, you can expect limited results for your query. I'm not trying to tell you what to do, but you will find writing your own very educational and a whole lot of fun.

Comment: Yeah I know how to write them, I just believe in the benefits of applies laziness.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one for **Google Charts:**

[Google Chart HtmlHelper for Asp.net Mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535576/google-chart-htmlhelper-for-asp-net-mvc)

As you can see by the Google Chart example, HTML Helper methods are not difficult to build, so it's easy enough to roll your own for whatever you want to do.  Just study the ASP.NET MVC source and see how they do it.

Comment: Yeah I know they're easy to write, I'm just essentially lazy and would prefer to re-use rather than re-invent.  Thanks for the link too.

Comment: +1 for the link.  Thanks @Robert.  I accepted the answer with the most votes as there doesn't seem to be a library as such out there.