# A real time chart for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, charts, real-time

I have an MVC application that displays current CPU usage accessed from WMI and refreshes this value within a 3 second-interval.(using the jquery setinterval function)

What I want to do , is I want to display a real time chart for this value on the same view page, identical to the one in TaskManager's performance tab.

Any suggestions?(I'm not very experienced with this, so I'd be glad if your response is not very high-level.)

Comment: try using flot : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758602/realtime-chart-using-flot-jquery

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm using flot now, it's easy-to-use. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [smoothie charts](http://smoothiecharts.org/) before and they are pretty cool and also look a bit like the task manager charts 'out of the box'.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with Google Chart Tools, see this question about integrating/using it from MVC:

[Google Chart HtmlHelper for Asp.net Mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535576/google-chart-htmlhelper-for-asp-net-mvc)

see this as well:

http://code.google.com/p/googlechartsharp/

Answer (score 0):

We're using [DevExpress XtraCharts](http://demos.devexpress.com/XtraChartsDemos/) for such tasks.

In your particular case, [Swift Plot Diagram](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/CustomDocument7093) is a good fit.

Controls are not free yet powerful and flexible.